# drupal rewrite is not working installed on subdomain

Tags: php, drupal

I have copied drupal from my main directory to anothre directory and created a sub domain but the url rewrite is not working.

I have checked mod_rewirte is enabled and allow override is set to all but I can not access pages except home page also I changed $base_url to point sub domain and also reflected in .htaccess.

Please advise what I can do from here also searched on net for this but nothing seems to be working

Thanks

Comment: If you disable Clean URLs, move the site, change $base_url, re-enable Clean URLs and clear all caches in this order, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot log in to turn off clean urls and you have access to the database you can edit the setting in the database.

in the 'variables' table find the row 'clean_urls' and delete the row. Then when the setting is checked it uses the default which is OFF.

In my experience this breaks when you move Drupal but miss the .htaccess file. Or if it is moved into a directory that forsome reason has AllowOverride turned off in apache settings.